# How to override the default wordpress search template and use woocommerce archive-product.php template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce site and for some reason the product search is displaying results using the wordpress search.php.

How can I override the default wordpress search template and use woocommerce archive-product.php template as normal. Using woocommerce product search widget.

I have woocommerce folder inside my theme and contains the archive-product.php, product-searchform.php

The shop page is using archive.php and I want the same template for search results.

**Code in my header for the form**

```
<div class="woo-search">
  <?php if(is_active_sidebar('woo-search')){
    dynamic_sidebar('woo-search');
  } ?>
</div>
```

How can I make the search results to display using archive-product.php?

Comment: copy and paste the code from archive-product.php into search.php

Comment: Tried this but does not work 100% in terms of the results returned. Some products not showing on the results.

Answer (score 0):

You've to use template_include filter. You have to add following code into your active theme's functions.php file.

The call back function checks the post type being searched. If it's the products it choose your desire template to list out search results.

```
function template_chooser($template) {    
  global $wp_query;   
  $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');   
  if( $wp_query->is_search && $post_type == 'products' )   
  {
    return locate_template('archive-product.php');  //  redirect to archive-product.php
  }   
  return $template;   
}
add_filter('template_include', 'template_chooser');
```

Let me know your feedback.

Comment: I have added this but it still goes to search.php

Comment: Finally got the problem. It was a function in my functions.php to disable single product page after add to cart. Had to replace that function with  add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'wp_get_referer' );

Comment: Ahh... Great! You got the solution, finally! Need to double check other hooks and files that override the behaviour of certain functionality.

Comment: I would recommend to use [wc_locate_template](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/namespaces/default.html#function_wc_locate_template) instead of the normal locate_template.